# "Not a managed type" error after spring/hibernate update

Tags: hibernate

After updating spring and hibernate we started getting the following error in some of our tests.

Spring: 6.1.3
Spring-boot: 3.2.2
Hibernate: 6.3.1.Final

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class a.b.c.MyClass
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:1)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
```

After stepping through the hibernate code I believe it is caused by this change
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/1184a5963bfd2bbc4ef2db1fe60d3e6de15584c7
Our entity classes implement java.util.Map so they get excluded from entityTypes in the registerEntityType method.

Is this no longer allowed or is there some configuration we need to do?